# Does any aspect of web development include oop

Tags: oop, web, vs-web-site-project

I have been given a programming project. One of the criteria for being marked is

"Complex user-defined use of objectorientated
programming (OOP) model,
eg classes, inheritance, composition,
polymorphism, interfaces"

I am thinking of building "a website with dynamic content driven by a database back end". However, I don't see where I could incorporate OOP into a website. Is it possible to do so? Should i just switch to making an app instead?

Comment: There is no real difference between a web application and an "app" as far as this exercise goes. You can use OOP in the data layer, business layer, view models, ... in either case. In the case of a web application you potentially have other classes in the objects used in the browser, so one more places to demonstrate your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement your web site based on Java (Java EE or Spring Boot), C#, Pyhon, the of course you will have to do with OOP.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to do a backend and a database ,you are most likely to use PHP and PDO/mysql/ respectively. And in OOP PHP you are definitely going to get what you are looking for like creating clases and as such. For example take a look at the example below taken from a PHP 5 manual:

```
<?php 
class Foo { 
       public $aMemberVar = 'aMemberVar Member Variable';
       public $aFuncName = 'aMemberFunc';
       function aMemberFunc() {
                  print 'Inside `aMemberFunc()`';
              } 
       } 

$foo = new Foo; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it easy you'll prefer to rely on MEAN stack ,
 MEAN is a framework for an easy starting point with MongoDB, Node.js, Express, and AngularJS based applications , 
Because AngularJS depends on OOP and you can mange your database by using  MongoDB 
but if you want builld just website python is good chosen and it is OOP